# Нужна ли запятая?

Tags: пунктуация

Нужна ли запятая после оборота "согласно чему-то"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Когда "согласно" предлог, запятыми может выделяться весь оборот.
Например: "Он, согласно нормам этикета, пропустил девушку вперед".
Если же предлог тесно связан по смыслу со сказуемым или является его частью, то оборот запятыми не выделяется.
Пример: *«Согласно правилам русского языка "не" с глаголами пишется раздельно».*